# OkHttp Interceptor is Null

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have this class to create a service with `retrofit2`:

```java
public class ServiceGenerator {

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(UrlProvider.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();


    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level logLevel = BuildConfig.DEBUG ?
            HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE;

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
            new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(logLevel);

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(logging)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();
                    Request request = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("HEADER_USER_AGENT", "USER_AGENT")
                            .method(original.method(), original.body())
                            .build();

                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });

            httpClient.authenticator(new TokenAuthenticator());
            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

I got this error in crash reporter:

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Null interceptor: [null, okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor@85a6f78, *.*.*.e.c@1f1feb6, *.*.*.e.c@66917b7]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    at *.*.*.S.run
    at *.*.*.Y.a
    at *.*.*.Y.e
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.build(OkHttpClient.java:1040)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.java:283)
```

This error occurs on some devices and in a special case.
The probability of call `createService` method from different thread.
Does ExecuterService help us?
How to fix this error? help me please.

Comment: Hello Masoud, welcome to StackOverflow; I have so many questions about this code, why all these static methods and fields? You'll need to debug and provide more information, is the interceptor there when you create the service? Does it disappear? when? I mean, why even do this to begin with, it's very strange and doesn't even look like a Factory pattern; I'd reconsider the architecture of what you're doing, why you're doing it, and if it's really saving you time or lines of code?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini In answer to this question, that why i used static method and field, I got the idea from this site : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-creating-a-sustainable-android-client